# Unable to get JSON response with Decodable in Swift

Tags: json, swift, decodable

in postman response structure like this:

```
 {
"categories": [
    {
        "id": 48,
        "name": "Round-The-Clock",
        "description": "24 hours round the clock menu",
        "status": "enabled",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 280,
                "name": ".Tea",.....
```

for this i have created Decodable model like this

```
 struct Categories: Codable {
let categories: [Category]?
let featuredProducts: [Product]?
 //coding keys..
 }
 struct Category: Codable {
let id: Int?
let name, categoryDescription: String?
let products: [Product]?
 }

 struct Product: Codable {
let id: Int?
let name, productDescription: String?
}
```

**Parsing code:** with this code break point hits with this `if let jsonData = try? decoder.decode(Categories.self, from: respData)` line but not hitting print("the categories are: (jsonData)") line and nothing comes in console, why? where am i wrong.. how to get response

```
class FoodMenuViewController: UIViewController {

private var catData: Categories? {
    didSet{ }
}

func foodMenuServicecall(){

let urlStr = "http://54.149.84.126/categories?shop=1"
let url = URL(string: urlStr)
var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
req.httpMethod = "GET"
req.addValue("X-Requested-With", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
req.addValue("XMLHttpRequest", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Requested-With")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

    guard let respData = data else {return}
    guard error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }
    do{
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let jsonData = try? decoder.decode(Categories.self, from: respData) {
            print("the categories are: \(jsonData)")
            self.catData = jsonData
        }
    }
    catch {print("catch error")}
}).resume()
}
```

EDIT: if i test like this i am getting response but here

```
 func foodMenuServicecall(){
    if let url = URL(string: "http://54.149.84.126//categories?shop=1"){
        var req = URLRequest(url: url)
        req.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"]

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: req) { data, _, err in
            guard let safeData = data else{return}
            print(String(data: safeData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

o/p in consol:

[image]

Comment: `print("catch error")` => `print("catch error: \(error)")`. `print("error")` => `ùprint("error: \(error)")`. `try?`: If there is an error, I don't want to hear about it. No, you are doing a do/catch, so just write `try` not `try?`.

Comment: Unrelated but `guard error == nil` will never be evaluated to `false` because when an error occurs `data` is `nil` and the closure is left *silently* in the line above.

Comment: @Larme, if i change `if let jsonData = try decoder.decode(Categories.self, from: respData)` then error:  `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Categories'`

Comment: Remove the `if let` then...

Comment: @Larme, catch error: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))

Comment: Do you really have a JSON valid response? Could you show the output, not the one in Postman.

Comment: @Larme, `URLSession.shared.dataTask` then got response in console... i have edited code with o/p console screen shot.. plz have a look once

Comment: It seems to be valid JSON at first glance... Maybe there is an invalid invisible character. Could you add `print(respData.prefix(10).map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242542/discussion-between-learn-swift-and-larme).

Answer (score 0):

Your decodable model expects a key of "categoryDescription", your JSON has a key of "description".